# Node-red Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, node-red

I am trying to deploy a simple node-red container on kubernetes locally to monitor its usage and at the same time create a persistent volume storage so that my node red work is saved. However, I can't get it to deploy to kubernetes. I have created a Deployment.yaml file with the following code

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodered
  name: nodered
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        limits:
        memory: 512Mi
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nodered-claim
          mountPath: /data/nodered
          # subPath: nodered <-- not needed in your case
      volumes:
      - name: nodered-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nodered-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: small-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nodered-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:enter image description here
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

I am getting this error in powershell:

```
kubectl apply -f ./Deployment.yaml
persistentvolume/small-pv unchanged
persistentvolumeclaim/nodered-claim unchanged
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/local-storage unchanged
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "./Deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].cpu", unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].limits", unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].memory", unknown field "spec.template.spec.requests"
```

I want it to deploy to kubernetes so that I can monitor the memory usage of the node red container

Comment: Node-Red because of its base platform(Node-JS) is entirely single threaded. Even if you put this on kubernetes with huge number of pods, somewhere down the road the whole app will be blocked at CPU limit of one of the POD. Both vertical and horizontal scaling is  infeasible. If you load is heavy, use a proper middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requests` & `limits` sections needs to be under a `resources` heading as follows:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nodered-claim
          mountPath: /data/nodered
          # subPath: nodered <-- not needed in your case
```

Answer (score -1):

Your deployment had a syntax error. Let's fix it to the right [syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)

It should be like this:

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: nodered
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "0.2"
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "1"
```

Comment: Answers need to contain the relevant details with links only for reference. This is because if the link breaks the answer will become useless.

Comment: Thank you so much it deployed correctly :D